# account for multiple function calls

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with some code that was around before I started at my work. The developers have left and it's up to me to add in some addition functionality.

What I am doing is logging a timestamp to a MySQL DB during certain sections of a php script.

My issue is that the script is being called twice. I can only find the actually function being called once.

```
Database Table
--------------
id    |  userID  | event  |  timestamp
---------------------------------------
1     |   4      |  5     | 2012-08-02 09:09:18
```

My question is if anybody knows a way to stop multiple db calls within a 2 second time period.

EDIT: preferably without a second db call

Comment: Find the code that's calling the function and stop it from calling the function. Do a [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) if necessary.

Comment: I think you should really focus on why this function is being call twice, instead of trying to patch it up with something else....

Comment: Guys, in general I agree that problems should be handled by fixing the cause and not by handling the symptom. But, in this case, the duplicate call could be caused by an impatient user that hits the `F5` button...

Comment: If this is dependent on the user NOT submitting more than once, you should display some message telling them to be patient, and not to refresh or navigate away from the page until it's done processing. This can be done with javascript (jQuery and AJAX, more specifically).

Comment: Regarding the last comment, you can also disable the submit button while the page is submitting. it will not prevent a refresh though...

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is called twice, add a `POST/GET` parameter that the page will submit and check, on the first call this parameter will have a `NULL` value but on every duplicate call it will have a value and you can use this value to prevent the script from updating the DB.

Comment: OPs function is being executed twice. Wouldn't it be more prudent to fix the code than to write a short-term hack?

Comment: @Matt the duplicate-execution could be caused by page refresh.

Comment: There's nothing in OPs post that would indicate that. Yes, that's a possibility, but that wouldn't be my first thought if he's running new functionality added to someone else's code.

Comment: I believe it is being caused by a page refresh now that it is brought up

Comment: @Matt actually a page refresh would be my first guess but that's just MY bad experience :)